# "Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only"

Tags: r, plot, anomaly-detection

### The Problem

**The plot here is not working, how can I show it?**

```
# minimal runnable code
# source: https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2015/introducing-practical-and-robust-anomaly-detection-in-a-time-series

install.packages("devtools") devtools::install_github("twitter/AnomalyDetection")
library(AnomalyDetection)
data(raw_data) 
res = AnomalyDetectionTs(raw_data, max_anoms=0.02, direction='both', plot=TRUE) 
res$plot
```

I get the following error:

```
> res$plot
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
```

### Additional Information

If it can be useful, this is the full output that I get once I press the button `Source` in RStudio:

```
# full output, including the error

> source("~/.active-rstudio-document", echo=TRUE)
> library(AnomalyDetection)
> data(raw_data) 
> res = AnomalyDetectionTs(raw_data, max_anoms=0.02, direction='both', plot=TRUE) 
> res$plot
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
>
```

In addition, here a sample of the dataset called `raw_data`:

```
# minimal dataset (printed)

> raw_data
              timestamp    count
1   1980-09-25 14:01:00 182.4780
2   1980-09-25 14:02:00 176.2310
3   1980-09-25 14:03:00 183.9170
4   1980-09-25 14:04:00 177.7980
5   1980-09-25 14:05:00 165.4690
6   1980-09-25 14:06:00 181.8780
7   1980-09-25 14:07:00 184.5020
8   1980-09-25 14:08:00 183.3030
9   1980-09-25 14:09:00 177.5780
10  1980-09-25 14:10:00 171.6410
```

Still the sample of my dataset called`raw_data`, by using `dput`:

```
# minimal dataset (dput)

> dput(raw_data[1:10, ])

structure(list(timestamp = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = 1:10, hour = c(14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), mday = c(25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), mon = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L), year = c(80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
80L), wday = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), yday = c(268L, 
268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 268L, 268L), isdst = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), count = c(182.478, 176.231, 183.917, 177.798, 
165.469, 181.878, 184.502, 183.303, 177.578, 171.641)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the AnomnalyDetection package but the sample of your dataset shows the timestamp column is of class `POSIXlt` and the error suggests you need it as `POSIXct` instead. Try using `as.POSIXct()` e.g.

```
raw_data$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(raw_data$timestamp)
```

before running the `AnomalyDetectionTs()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cnbrownlie, however, by running the code with your suggestion:
`````````````
library(AnomalyDetection)
raw_data$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(raw_data$timestamp)
res = AnomalyDetectionTs(raw_data, max_anoms=0.02, direction='both', plot=TRUE)
res$plot
`````````````
I still get the error:
`````````````
> res$plot
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
`````````````